# My PHP MySQL statement does not stop running

Tags: javascript, php

I create a script that gets some JavaScript var's and inserts them into a MySQL database, the problem is that it does not stop running, he keeps inserting the same data over and over on the database. I really don't know what could be, maybe those 4 lines of the $stmt/the whole if sentence?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href='insertsql.php?email=myemail@email.com&at=2&af=3&pe=2&ar=3&de=2&he=3'
</script>

<?php
$servername="secretserver";
$username="secretname";
$password="password";
$dbname="database";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connecion failed".$conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

if (isset($_GET['email'],$_GET['at'],$_GET['af'],$_GET['pe'],$_GET['ar'],$_GET['de'],$_GET['he'])){

    $email=$_GET["email"];
    $at=$_GET["at"];
    $af=$_GET["af"];
    $pe=$_GET["pe"];
    $ar=$_GET["ar"];
    $de=$_GET["de"];
    $he=$_GET["he"];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO mydatabase (email_nome, dummy_one, dummy_two, dummy_three, dummy_four, dummy_five, dummy_six) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $email , $at, $af, $pe, $ar, $de, $he);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: You don't have any control on your `window.location`. It will load the page, run that line, load the page, run that line, putting you in a never ending loop.

Comment: Oh yesss, in the final code this javascript will run with a press of a button, that will fix the problem right?

Comment: yes it would, although you'd also need something in the PHP to check that the data was actually submitted before attempting to read it from $_GET and put it into the database. P.S. For a set of fields like this, using POST with a form would be a much more appropriate technique.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing this page does is execute all of the PHP code server-side, which inserts a record into the database.

The second thing this page does is execute one line of code client-side which reloads the page:

```
window.location.href='insertsql.php?email=myemail@email.com&at=2&af=3&pe=2&ar=3&de=2&he=3'
```

So after each insert operation, you instruct the page to start over again.  Simply remove that one JavaScript operation, it serves no purpose other than to do the exact thing you're saying you don't want it to do.